# Respond with Cache headers for images in Ktor

Tags: caching, kotlin, ktor

What is the correct way to send back cache headers for static images being served by Ktor?

I have the following Ktor setup:

In my `main`:

```
embeddedServer(
        Netty,
        watchPaths = listOf("module"),
        module = Application::module,
        port = if (ENV.env == LOCAL) {
            8080
        } else {
            80
        }
    ).apply {
        start(wait = true)
    }
```

and then outside the main:

```
fun Application.module() {
    if (ENV.env != LOCAL) {
        install(ForwardedHeaderSupport)
        install(XForwardedHeaderSupport)
        install(HttpsRedirect)
    }
    install(CachingHeaders) {
        options { outgoingContent ->
            when (outgoingContent.contentType?.withoutParameters()) {
                ContentType.Image.Any -> CachingOptions(CacheControl.MaxAge(maxAgeSeconds = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60))
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }
    install(Compression) {
        gzip {
            priority = 1.0
        }
        deflate {
            priority = 10.0
            minimumSize(1024) // condition
        }
    }

    routing {
        static("/js/") {
            resources("/js/")
        }

        static("/css/") {
            resources("/css/")
        }

        static("/favicons") {
            resources("/favicons/")
        }

        static("/img/") {
            resources("/static/img/")
            resources("/static/images/")
            resources("/background/")
            resources("/logos/")
            resources("/icons/")
        }
    }
}
```

The images however are coming back with no caching headers, any ideas?

[image]

**Update**:

Changing `ContentType.Image.Any` to `ContentType.Image.JPEG` seems to work. Looking at the source code of `Image`, it seems to map to ContentType(`image`, `*`) but is not matching any image type at all.

```
install(CachingHeaders) {
    options { outgoingContent ->
        when (outgoingContent.contentType?.withoutParameters()) {
            ContentType.Image.JPEG -> CachingOptions(
                cacheControl = CacheControl.MaxAge(
                    mustRevalidate = false,
                    maxAgeSeconds = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                    visibility = CacheControl.Visibility.Public
                )
            )
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

Filed a bug in the meantime: 
https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that a standard eqauls check is being done on `*` instead of the actual file type, so using match instead sorts that problem out:

```
install(CachingHeaders) {
    options { outgoingContent ->
        if (outgoingContent.contentType?.withoutParameters()?.match(ContentType.Image.Any) == true) {
            CachingOptions(
                cacheControl = CacheControl.MaxAge(
                    mustRevalidate = false,
                    maxAgeSeconds = 6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                    visibility = CacheControl.Visibility.Public
                )
            )
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set caching headers by content type using: https://ktor.io/servers/features/caching-headers.html

Comment: like what i'm doing in the code in my question? `ContentType.Image.Any -> CachingOptions(CacheControl.MaxAge(maxAgeSeconds = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60))`